# Renaming an Excel worksheet generates an error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to rename an excel sheet to the contents of a cell on that sheet using VBA.

I have created a separate module called Rename_Sheets and various posts online suggest the following code:

```
Sheets(3).Name = Sheet3.Range("A5")
```

or very similar variations thereof.

Using debug.print, both parts of the above code return the expected results, i.e. the sheet name and the cell text.
When I run the code as quoted I get the message "Application-defined or object defined error".
I don't understand why I get the error message.

Comment: You haven't given us anything to go on. What is the value of `Sheet3.Range("A5")`?

Answer (score 0):

u have a typo

replace

```
 Sheet3.Range("A5")
```

to

```
 Sheets(3).Range("A5")
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

`Sheet3.Range("A5")` returns a Range Object. What you want instead is the Value Property of the returned Range Object:

```
Sheets(3).Name = Sheet3.Range("A5").Value
```

Note though, that once the code runs once and Sheet3 is renamed, it will start throwing an error again because "Sheet3" will not exist. If you made it `Sheets(3).Range("A5").Value` similar to the other side of the equal sign, this code would would work more than once.

Comment: The spreadsheet I am using is a template which asks the user to input data including a month name. That data is entered in cell A5 on sheet 3, and I want to rename that sheet to display the month name. This procedure will only run once when a new spreadsheet is created using this template. I have changed the code to read Sheets(3).Name = Sheets(3).Range("A5").Value as suggested but still get the same error message. Using debug.print, the first expression returns "Purchases 1" - the name given in the template - and the second expression returns "October purchases" following user input.

Comment: @PwB I was unable to recreate what you're experiencing. Is there any other code in the Sub other than the one line in my answer? It's possible that the error is coming from another line of code, or the setup of your spreadsheet. Open a brand new excel file, open the VBA editor and put in nothing but the one line of code inside of a Sub() and write "Hello World" in A5 of sheet 3 and see if your error still happens.

Comment: In a new workbook the sub with just one line (under "ThisWorkbook") works fine. When I copy that sub into my template in the same location the error recurs. Any suggestions why that may happen?

Comment: I get the "Application-defined [...]" error if A5 is blank, but if you're getting the error when A5 has a value, maybe try: (1) rewrite `Sheet(3).Range("A5")` to `Sheets(3).Cells(5,1)` | (2) Instead of having the code in ThisWorkbook move it to a module with no other code inside of it | (3) If all else fails and your workbook is small enough, do a Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C in every sheet, paste it into a new workbook, bring over only this module of your VBA, test it, if it works bring over the rest of your VBA and see if it still works.

Comment: Problem solved! Many thanks Tyler N I had to copy everything into a new workbook/template and it all works OK..New workbooks based on the new template get the data from the user and place it in the correct places in the workbook, including updating the sheet names. I just don't know why it wouldn't work in the previous template!!!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you have a working template now! Sometimes computers do things that are very weird to humans... Glad to have helped.